# Trilogy in the 80’s about space travel to another world

Tags: story-identification, books, space-exploration, space-colonization

Growing up in the 80's my mother introduced me to a trilogy she read. I don’t remember the name but they traveled to another world and worked to colonize it. 2064 or something idk. The books were paperback and fairly thick. I think the colors of the books were blue orange and green. Went through stages from Earth to the planet and their encounters.

Comment: This is far too vague. The only distinguishing features I can make out here are that it's a trilogy about colonising another world and set in the future (with a blue cover). That matches *a lot* of potential books.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_trilogy

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: When did these books were presented?

Answer (score 15):

This is presumably the [*Red Mars*, *Green Mars*, *Blue Mars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_trilogy) trilogy by Kim Stanley Robinson, published over the years from 1992 to 1996.  It fits the general description, with thick novels, mostly read in paperback, about the colonization of another planet in the twenty-first century.

Comment: It's amazing how many people think that these publication dates match "in the 80's".  It's one of the few pieces of actual information in the question, and it does not match.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP It does however match the trilogy, colors, emphasis on colonization (as opposed to, say, some conflict on visited planet), futuristic settings as well as stages of development. That sounds sufficient, doesn't it?

Comment: Only if one holds that the questioner is more likely to have remembered a book cover than _the questioner's own age_, and what decade xe grew up in.  And if one retitles one book _Orange Mars_.  (-:  Jerry Pournelle´s Falkenberg novels are as mediocre a match as this.  There were three of them by the end of the correct decade, they had 2064 in their timeline too, _West of Honour_ had at least one blue cover, and several of the covers of _The Mercenary_ were actual orange.